# DateTime and culture

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

SQL:

```
select * 
from tvideoconference 
where del = 'false' 
and iduserpatient = 0 and startdate >= N'18.02.2013 20:37:07'  
order by startdate
```

Error:

> *The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

I got this error, when I tried to use method below in `de-DE` session culture. What is more, in `pl-PL` and `en-US` culture, this methods works perfect.

```
public static DataSet getSpecialistConfs(int iduserspecialist)
{
    DateTime? today = DateTime.Now;
    today = today.Value.AddHours(-today.Value.Hour).AddMinutes(-(today.Value.Minute + 1));
    string sql = "select * from tvideoconference where del='false' and startdate >=N'" + today.Value + "' and iduserspecialist=" + iduserspecialist;
    sql += " order by startdate ";

    return Tools.SQLTools.getDataSet(sql);
}
```

How can I resolve it? I tried with many solutions (substrings, date format), with the same effect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and date format settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I resolve it?

Use parameterized SQL in the first place. Don't include the values in your query itself; use parameters and set the values of those parameters.

It's unclear what `Tools.SqlTools` is, but you *really, really* should use parameterized SQL. That way you won't be converting the `DateTime` value into a string to start with, so cultures and formatting can't get in the way. Additionally, you won't be vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)...

(Additionally, it's not at all clear why you're using `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` - it's not like `DateTime.Now` can be null... and you should consider using `DateTime.Today` instead... or `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`.)

Comment: thanks for reply. I understand this, but I'm interesting about why this method works with other cultures, and don't work with "de-DE" culture. I don't have a reasonable argument for this situation.